# django rest api __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-3.2

api link is not working. show this error "**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Please help me. I am beginner in django

trying to creat blog api
model.py:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    blog_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

view.py

```
class BlogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BlogSerializer
    permission_classes = IsAuthenticated
    queryset = Blog.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

serializer.py:

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from . import views
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
)

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('blogs', views.BlogViewSet, basename='blogs')

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/login', views.MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
    path('users/register', views.register_user, name='register'),
    path('users/profile', views.get_user_profile, name='profile'),

    path('blogs/', views.BlogViewSet, name='blogs'),
    path('avatar/', views.get_avatar, name='avatar'),
]
```

so when i perform a get request to "http://localhost:8000/api/blogs/" it shows this error:

```
TypeError at /api/blogs/

__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/api/blogs/
Django Version:     3.2.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Exception Location:     D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 181, in _get_response
Python Executable:  D:\work environment\Django_Api\codersavvy\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.9.2
Python Path:    

['D:\\work environment\\Django_Api\\codersavvy',
 'C:\\Users\\S\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\S\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\S\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\S\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'D:\\work environment\\Django_Api\\codersavvy',
 'D:\\work environment\\Django_Api\\codersavvy\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Mon, 14 Jun 2021 17:28:12 +0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.as_view()` to turn the (class-based) `ViewSet` into a function that will dispatch HTTP calls:

```
path('blogs/', views.BlogViewSet.as_view(), name='blogs'),
```

Since you however made a `ViewSet`, you can use a [*router* [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) with:

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from . import views
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
)

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('blogs', views.BlogViewSet, basename='blogs')

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/login', views.MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
    path('users/register', views.register_user, name='register'),
    path('users/profile', views.get_user_profile, name='profile'),

    path('avatar/', views.get_avatar, name='avatar'),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Comment: thank for your kind help. after that I'm getting this errors ``` AttributeError at /api/blogs/
'BlogSerializer' object has no attribute 'get_user' ```

Comment: @techedifice: you can not specify `user` as `SerializerMethodField` in the serializer, since that would mean that there is a method in the serializer `get_user`, but that is not the case.

Comment: @techedifice: you can perhaps work with the [**`StringRelatedSerializer`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield), or something else that tells the serializer how to serialize the user.